# File upload not in Update panel hasfile coming false even if file is present in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

> i am trying to upload the file but all the time `hasfile` is coming
>   `false`. why file upload control is also not in update panel
>   i have even check file is not empty as pointed by other answers in stackoverflow.

**.aspx file**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label ID="AddDoc_SelectHeadLabel" runat="server" Text="Select File:" AssociatedControlID="file"></asp:Label>

    <asp:FileUpload ID="file" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />

</div>
<div class="text-right">
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vs1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="DocumentvalGroup" ShowSummary="false" ShowMessageBox="false" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="AddDoc_SaveButton" runat="server" validationgroup="DocumentvalGroup"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>&nbsp;Upload</button>
    <button type="button" id="cancelButton" runat="server" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-leftspace" style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>&nbsp;Cancel</button>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="AddDoc_SaveButton" />
    </Triggers>
</div>
```

C# code

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try {
        if (Session["CheckRefresh"].ToString() == ViewState("CheckRefresh").ToString()) {
            if (file.HasFile) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `asp:PostBackTrigger` which `ControlID` pointed to your submit button?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes tried just now still not working code updated

Comment: I think this is wrong: `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="file" />`. I suggest this (from 1st revision): `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="AddDoc_SaveButton" />` & use `Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data")` in `Form_Load` event.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto added/edited code what u have told and as far as writing in pageload  i have written the upload file in User control

Comment: Have you checked if uploaded file is exist using `HttpPostedFile`: `HttpPostedFile posted = file.PostedFile`? I suspected since you're not using `UpdatePanel` the `PostBackTrigger` needs to be changed with `AsyncPostBackTrigger` or just use standard `<input type="file" ... />` instead `FileUpload`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply this code will work for file upload.

ASPX:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <asp:Label ID="AddDoc_SelectHeadLabel" runat="server" Text="Select File:" AssociatedControlID="file"></asp:Label>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="file" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" OnClick="btn_Save_Click" Text="Save" />
</div>
```

C#:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (file.HasFile) //true
            {
                //Comes here.
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AkhilJain From where are you calling the method "btnSave_Click" in aspx? The shared code is working for me.

Comment: has file is coming FALSE always @Manoj Gopi

Answer (score 0):

I think `FileUpload` is in `UpdatePanel` for this porton:

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="AddDoc_SaveButton" />
</Triggers>
```

`FileUpload` doesn't work when nested in `UpdatePanel`. You just need to make your button do a full `postback` to send the file. `AsyncPostbacks` don't work with files for security reasons.

Comment: @AkhilJain you used `<Triggers>` in your code that it used in `update pannel`?